# P2SH-P2WPKH - has always segwit UTXOs?

Tags: raw-transaction, p2sh, p2wpkh

I've been reading a lot of docs on BTC transaction structure, and find it really confusing when it comes to SegWit story.

So, the very first thing is, if I've P2SH-P2WPKH address, does it mean that all outputs to this address (UTXOs) are by definition segwit UTXOs ?

In the docs (https://bitcoincore.org/en/segwit_wallet_dev/) it says:

> **Signature Generation and Verification for P2SH-P2WPKH**
>
> For spending of non-segwit UTXO, the signature generation algorithm is  unchanged.
>
> For spending of P2SH-P2WPKH:
>
> - The scriptSig MUST ONLY contain a push of the redeemScript
>
> ...

So, either all UTXOs for P2SH-P2WPKH address are segwit ones, or they are SegWit if SegWit transaction was made to this address (which does little sense actually for me, as then arises chicken-egg problem).

Why they wrote this *"For spending of non-segwit UTXO, the signature generation algorithm is  unchanged"* part, what case it covers? If you've P2SH-P2WPKH address but you are taking some foreign UTXOs to spend(that were directed not to your address)?

Another not clear part are scripts for P2SH-P2WPKH address.
So here is my example address:
3MxYPuvEcKDdaEG1xoGyddqir6C4b66MJi

And here is transaction that was made to it:
https://blockchain.info/rawtx/6c2806587d5cdb3f0363e43f60b4a84baf37b3012fbde02f108f4eb1bdcede42

Based on it pubKeyScript of output is **a914de523116b281c96ff1e204ea2ff435b75d48f0de87** which translates to:

```
OP_HASH160 de523116b281c96ff1e204ea2ff435b75d48f0de OP_EQUAL
```

So, **de523116b281c96ff1e204ea2ff435b75d48f0de** is hash160 of redeem script.
The only redeem script that matches this hash I've found is following:

```
0 389f26d8d616cb96df1cfd6d9989248a30b933b9
```

Which is witness v0 program script(0 sha160sha256(pubkey), so it means I've to create SegWit transactions, right?
I tried making P2SH ones and it says that I've non-nominal pushes in the redeem script, that's cause of "0" push there I believe.

I feel that doing something wrong in this part, and as a result signing either wrong thing or in a wrong way...

Very appreciate any explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I've P2SH-P2WPKH address, does it mean that all outputs to this
>   address (UTXOs) are by definition segwit UTXOs ?

Yes, Bitcoin sent to a `P2SH-P2WPKH` address will produce a segwit `UTXO`.

> Why they wrote this "For spending of non-segwit UTXO, the signature
>   generation algorithm is unchanged" part, what case it covers? If
>   you've P2SH-P2WPKH address but you are taking some foreign UTXOs to
>   spend(that were directed not to your address)?

I think you're right, it sounds like it's just saying if you want to send to a segwit address, you don't need to sign a non-segwit input any differently than before.

### Spending P2SH(P2WPKH)

Here is a good reference example: [BIP 141: P2SH(P2WPKH)](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#p2wpkh-nested-in-bip16-p2sh). In order to spend Bitcoin sent to your address `3MxYPuvEcKDdaEG1xoGyddqir6C4b66MJi`, you have to provide the following:

```
witness:      <signature> <pubkey>
scriptSig:    <0 <20-byte-key-hash>>
              (0x160014{389f26d8d616cb96df1cfd6d9989248a30b933b9})
```

Perhaps you are forgetting the push ops `0x16` and/or `0x14` in `scriptSig`?

Comment: `Yes, Bitcoin sent to a P2SH-P2WPKH address will produce a segwit UTXO.` Technically, the utxo type is still p2sh. It's only revealed as segwit when it is spent. You could totally spend it as a p2sh if you can brute force a redeem script that satisfies the hash and is solvable by you, although that's rather impossible. Regardless, the output itself is p2sh.

Comment: @RaghavSood True, there would be no way to detect that it was a segwit UTXO, because it's the redeem script that is segwit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments, now it's more clear what is what :)
I don't have 0x16, here is mine full script:

     "script": "0014389f26d8d616cb96df1cfd6d9989248a30b933b9", 

Is 0x16 required also?

Comment: Basically here is serialized tx I've

0100000000010142decebdb14e8f102fe0bd2f01b337af4ba8b4603fe463033fdb5c7d5806286c00000000160014389f26d8d616cb96df1cfd6d9989248a30b933b9ffffffff0210270000000000001976a914eeba84c4b62a6b6db8f1e0a1daffa0eccde33adf88acbe2100000000000017a914de523116b281c96ff1e204ea2ff435b75d48f0de8702483045022100fc44e10e8ab2e344c7e90f04f4f21a313850cd8eaebb0320edbc5e2d34c749b70220369da1b85125babd90a067d47e4034bc15ca1b9631ed5c8554148be3a4349d19012102ed991ef73f82488def8031fcccc4d51de840e7f17e3ad5d820781df0b4ee6e0600000000

Comment: You need the `0x16` because it tells the interpreter to push the following 22 bytes (redeem script) to the stack.